# Access the EMMC flash on VxWorks

Tags: driver, vxworks, fat32

I want to access my EMMC from my VxWorks Software.

My hardware is  - Kontron SMARC-sAMX6i

My VxWorks version - 6.9

I have formatted my EMMC to FAT32 using a Linux computer, and I can access it on the UBOOT stage using a micro USB and these 2 commands on UBOOT:

```
mmc dev 2.
ums 0 mmc 2.
```

When my VxWorks OS loaded I can see it recognized("/mmc0:0") my device using "devs" on VxWorks Shell:

```
drv name
  0 /null
  1 /tyCo/0
  1 /tyCo/1
  1 /tyCo/2
  7 /sysNvRam
  7 /usrNvRam
  8 /hal
  9 /i2c0
  9 /i2c1
  9 /i2c2
 11 /vio
 12 /tgtsvr
  3 /ram0
  3 /sd
  4 /mmc0:0
value = 25 = 0x19
```

The problem is when my VxWorks OS is loaded I can't access my EMMC using VxWorks Shell and commit commands such as "ls" or "cd".
I have tried to format it from the VxWorks shell as DOSFS using "dosFsVolFormat" but every time the format is finished it initiated again to raw FS.

Example from VxWorks Shell:

```
dosFsVolFormat "/mmc0:0"
Formatting /mmc0:0 for DOSFS
Instantiating /mmc0:0 as rawFs, device = 0x60001
Formatting...Retrieved old volume params with %70 confidence:
Volume Parameters: FAT type: FAT32, sectors per cluster 0
  0 FAT copies, 0 clusters, 4192 sectors per FAT
  Sectors reserved 0, hidden 0, FAT sectors 0
  Root dir entries 0, sysId (null)  , serial number 40002004
  Label:"           " ...
Disk with 7438336 sectors of 512 bytes will be formatted with:
Volume Parameters: FAT type: FAT32, sectors per cluster 8
  2 FAT copies, 927972 clusters, 7264 sectors per FAT
  Sectors reserved 32, hidden 0, FAT sectors 14528
  Root dir entries 0, sysId VX5DOS32, serial number 40002004
  Label:"           " ...
Instantiating /mmc0:0 as rawFs,  device = 0x60001
OK.
value = 0 = 0x0
```

I am very confused about this problem and haven't succeeded to find any solution for it I will be happy for any advice or guidance.

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Hi thank. Anyone have some advise?

Comment: when you say "VxWorks shell" what exactly do you mean? There are 2 interpreters: what's called the 'C interpreter' (shell prompt "->") which is, as the name suggests, used to run C code, generally by calling functions that have been exposed via the global symbol table. Then there is the command interpreter (shell prompt "[vxWorks]#"), which you get to by typing 'cmd' into the C interpreter. This is where you can run filesystem commands like cd, ls, etc. 
  
So:  

`-> cmd  

[vxWorks]# ls mmc0:0`